# Forcing SSL + WWW in .htaccess whilst enabling other subomains

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

Please could someone explain how to change the following extract from my .htaccess file to force SSL + www. and allow access to subdomains.

At the moment, all users are forced to use SSL but they are able to access the site via https://www.domain.co.uk AND https://domain.co.uk (instead of just https://www.domain.co.uk). At the same time, they are unable to access subdomains. If they try to do this they are redirected from http://sub.domain.co.uk to https://sub.domain.co.uk to http://www.domain.co.uk/sub (instead of from http://sub.domain.co.uk to http://sub.domain.co.uk)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.DOMAIN.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In addition to this code, I also have a number of (100+) 302 redirects e.g.

```
Redirect 302 /ProductName http://www.NEWDOMAIN.com/ProductName
```

These redirects currently sit between  `RewriteEngine On` and

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do this without messing with other subdomains and ensuring your regular domain always goes to https.

Replace this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.DOMAIN.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
```

with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Based on your comment.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(subfolder1|subfolder2)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(subfolder1|subfolder2)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Just one question... If I wanted to exclude a couple subdirectory e.g. https://www.domain.co.uk/subfolder how would I modify the above code? At the moment I have a couple of (png) files stored in a subdirectory and I just get a 404 error when trying to view them.